# How to insert Currency values into salesforce object using CreateSalesforceObject

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using AMPScript to insert values into salesforce custom object. Inserting String values is working fine but for salesforce data type Currency(16,2) I am getting error. I have tried FormatCurrency function without any luck.

```
%%[

var @p_cost , @insertthis

set @p_cost = [product cost]
set @p_cost =  FormatCurrency(@p_cost,"en_GB", 2) 

set @insertthis = CreateSalesforceObject("myObject__c", 1, "p_cost__c", @p_cost)

]%%
```

Anybody have any idea?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Please comment out your CreateSalesforceObject() line and output @p_cost and then update your question to include the values displayed.  There's no way to help you without some sample data or output.

Comment: Thanks Adam
1. If I display the value I can see the value e:g 12.40 displayed.
2. If I hard code the value for that field as string its get inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my original data coming from salesforce itself as Currency and saved in marketing cloud as decimal.

I have used FormatNumber function to convert to number and it saved back to Salesforce object perfectly.

```
set @p_cost = FormatNumber(@p_cost,"N2")
```

Thanks all those who helped to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

When passing currency data using the CreateSalesforceObject() or UpdateSingleSalesforceObject() **AMPScript** functions, the currency value must be passed as a number.  The appropriate currency symbol to use is manages in the Salesforce ORG settings.   You can manage the default default currency for an ORG by going to: setup / Company Profile / Company Information and edit the Currency Locale field.

While testing the **AMPScript** functions, I was able to successfully pass the following values in a currency field.

```
set @p_cost = 12.40
set @p_cost = "12.40"
set @p_cost = "12.40555"
set @p_cost = 12.40555
```

However, the below values caused the **AMPScript** function to fail.

```
set @p_cost = FormatCurrency(@p_cost,"en_GB", 2) 
set @p_cost = £12.40
set @p_cost = "£12.40"
set @p_cost = "$12.40"
```

Comment: Thanks David, 
set @p_cost = FormatNumber(@p_cost,"N2")

This sort the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe format function may meet your requirements
%%=Format("$100.00","$#,#.00;-$#,#.00")=%%

you can find more details on formats on below link http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Format    Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried Format as well without any luck.